# Issue with JOIN command

Tags: sql, database, join

Hi New comer to Stack overflow so if I do not present this correctly I am sorry.

I have used Google, W3schools and read the FQA on SQL.

I am running SQL using the SQL command line in WAMP2.0. I am currently doing a project where the aim is to create a min University DB. With students, grades, programmes, modules ect

One of the tasks is to to list all the students, there modules and there correspoding grades. To do this I am trying to use a JOIN command to select all the names from the Students table, with all there corresponding modules + grades from the records table.

```
+------------+-------+------------+-----------------+
| Student_id | Name  | DOB        | Address         |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------------+
|    4665236 | Paddy | 1985-09-18 | 123 Fake Street |
|    5665236 | Paul  | 1984-06-12 | Good manlane    |
|    6665236 | John  | 1984-03-09 | Docotor town    |
|    7665236 | Aidan | 1983-07-09 | Banker worlds   |
|    8665236 | Joe   | 1983-07-09 | 24 hitherwood   |
+------------+-------+------------+-----------------+

+------------+--------+------+-------+
| Student_id | Mod_id | GPA  | Grade |
+------------+--------+------+-------+
|    4655236 |   2222 | 3.84 | A-    |
|    5655236 |  11111 | 3.44 | B+    |
|    6655236 |  33333 | 3.24 | B     |
|    7655236 |  44444 | 2.45 | C-    |
|    8655236 |  44444 | 2.45 | C-    |
+------------+--------+------+-------+
```

The PRIMARY KEY in the students table is Student_id INT 11

The PRIMARY KEY for records is (Student_id,Mod_id)

Individual SELECT FROM , statements work fine on both tables.

Issue occurs when I use

```
SELECT students.Name, records.Grade
FROM students
INNER JOIN records
ON students.Student_id=Student_id
ORDER BY students.Name
```

I get the following error

> ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'Student_id' in on clause is ambiguous

Thanks for amazingly fast response I tried

> SELECT students.Name, records.Grade
>   FROM students
>   INNER JOIN records
>   ON students.Student_id=records.Student_id
>   ORDER BY students.Name;

And Got ---- Empty set (0.00 sec) ?

Comment: Try `students.Student_id = records.student_id` in your ON clause.

Comment: You have two correct answers so I'll just explain something.  Some error messages are vague.  This one is not.  When ever you see it, it means that the field exists in more than one table and you did not specify which one.  This is called qualifying the field.  JW does it with the table names and Mahmoud uses aliases.

Comment: But there are no matching `Student_Id` between the two tables, your query won't return any rows.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

You have to qualify that column `Student_Id` with an alias, something like `records.studentId` so that it will be un ambiguous in the `ON` clause, or:

```
SELECT s.Name, r.Grade
FROM students AS s
INNER JOIN records AS r ON s.Student_id= r.Student_id
ORDER BY s.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the table name for column `Student_id` to avoid ambiguity because it both exist on the two tables.

```
SELECT students.Name, records.Grade
FROM   students
       INNER JOIN records
          ON students.Student_id = records.Student_id -- << THIS
ORDER  BY students.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for amazingly fast response I tried this and was given ----------- Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @user1955349 see the last line of my answer below. You don't have any matching records in the two tables you've presented here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're column name is being flagged as ambiguous is because you've got two different tables that each have the `Student_id` field. You can join a table to itself, so even though you've got an identifier on the first instance of the field you need one on both.

Try the following code:

```
SELECT students.Name, records.Grade
FROM students
INNER JOIN records
ON students.Student_id=records.Student_id
ORDER BY students.Name
```

You can also alias the tables if that helps your code look cleaner by using the following:

```
SELECT s.Name, r.Grade
FROM students s
INNER JOIN records r
ON s.Student_id=r.Student_id
ORDER BY s.Name
```

However, this only works if the Student IDs match in both tables. in the example data you've presented there are no matching records.  4665236 != 4655236

Comment: Ok Sorry if I am being an idiot...but wouldn't Student_Id 4665236  in students match to Student_id 4665236  in records?

Comment: yes, but look carefully at what you posted. you've got 4655 not 4665 in the records table.

Comment: Oh Jebus ...thank a lot man! - If I had reputation I would up vote you!